# Create nested directories with the same user/group in a single command

Tags: command-line, permissions

Is there a way to create nested directories which all have the same user/group in a single command?

That single command would have the same effect as the following two commands:

```
mkdir -p new-1/new-2/new-3
chown -R myUser:myUser new-1
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is no single command that I can think of that would do this, unless you count calling a shell function that performs both steps as "a single command".

Comment: @Kusalananda Ah, okay then. Thanks anyway. I could just stick a semicolon or && between them of course, but was just curious if I had missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not add a comment, therefore I post this as an answer.
Have a look at `install`, see `man install(1)`.

`install -d -g myUser -o myUser new-1 new-1/new-2 new-1/new-2/new-3`

Or, if you don't want to repeat the directory names (using root user):

`sudo -g myUser -u myUser mkdir -p new-1/new-2/new-3`

Comment: Note that `install -d -o user -g group dir/dir/dir` creates all intermediate directories but does _not_ set the correct user or group ownerships on them (only on the last directory).  Using `install` is therefore a good idea that unfortunately misses the mark.

Comment: But: `install -d -g group -o user a a/b a/b/c`, just one command.

Comment: You may want to put that in your answer, together with how you take `new-1/new-2/new-3` and turn it into `new-1 new-1/new-2 new-1/new-2/new-3`, which I assume the user would need to do as part of the command.

Comment: @OliverKnodel Install worked great, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks